# Bank transfer to fake or fraudulent recipient

Tags: united-kingdom, banking, scams

I have made a bank transfer from my UK account to another UK account but then I have realised that the recipient's name was fake and I got scammed. I requested my bank and the recipient's bank the money back but they refused, so I requested to the banks the real name of the payee and they refused again. 
I would like to go to the Court but I don't know the real name of the payee, I have just the bank details. Is there a way to request the money back or to request the judge to unveil the real recipient's details?

Thank you very mucch to anyone will be so kind to help me.

Comment: This might not be on-topic for PFF.  Law.SE seem to be more suitable.

Comment: Don't go to court go to the police. Report the scam, and if there is anything that can be done to trace the scammer they will do it.

Comment: First of all use the bank's internal process to dispute the transaction. In the next step go to the financial ombudsman. https://www.financial-ombudsman.org.uk/businesses/complaints-deal/banking-and-payments  The ombudsman won't look into your complaint unless you have used the bank's process for remediation

Comment: Who do you bank with? If it's TSB, and you're ["clearly an innocent victim of fraud", they'll give you your money back](https://www.tsb.co.uk/fraud-prevention-centre/). Who knows what's hiding behind that 'clearly, of course...

Answer (score -1):

Consult an experienced attorney (or equivalent) that specializes in bank fraud to determine what (if any) remedies are available.